# RestSharp - Delegating handlers with HttpTracerHandler

Tags: c#, restsharp

In the RestSharp documentation here (https://restsharp.dev/v107/#delegating-handlers)
there's a code snippet that looks like this:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(_server.Url) {
    ConfigureMessageHandler = handler => 
        new HttpTracerHandler(handler, new ConsoleLogger(), HttpMessageParts.All)
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

I would like to use this but I can't seem to figure out how to reference the `HttpTracerHandler` class.  Am I missing something or was this just an example name of something I need to create?

Comment: THat's part of an open source library available at https://github.com/BSiLabs/HttpTracer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation links to the HttpTracer [repository](https://github.com/BSiLabs/HttpTracer) right above the code snippet you mentioned.